# mvc ajax to controller and redirect to another controllerr

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is my code. I ajax to controller and return to another controller but nothing append.
I have search the problem but i did not found my answer .
I wanna pass parameters to another controller without query string 
I don't want client see my parameters
What should i do please help

```
$.ajax({
    url : "home/search",
    type: "POST",
    data : {city :"" , date: ""},
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
   });


public actionresult search(string city, datetime date ){

 return RedirectToAction("search");
}

public actionresult search(){

return view();
}
```

Comment: Ajax calls stay on the same page so `return RedirectToAction("search");` in your method is just ignored.

Comment: i know mvc url rewriting, attribute routing, cookies.  but again i can't hide parrameters from client user

Comment: Try `return this.search()` instead

Comment: Why are you even trying to do this? The user can always open the developer tools and see exactly what was posted anyway (nothing you can do to prevent that). In any case, the values you are posting are either values that the user entered (so **they** already know them) or values you must have passed to the view, in which case **you** already know them so why do they need to be posted.

Comment: @jumpingcode i know that . but i doing this for seo, i want my ulr become friendly like websitename/flight/London if user come from google i recognize and will give suggest london flights .its not for securities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this solution if we post parameters with hidden inputs url will been clear .

```
     post('result',
            {
                HotelOfferId: HotelOfferId,
                FlightOfferId: FlightOfferId,
                Residence: Residence,
                Nationality: Nationality,
                Checkin: CheckinString,
                Checkout: CheckoutString,
                FlightGuid: ""
            });



function post(path, params, method) {
method = method || "post";
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", method);
form.setAttribute("action", path);
for (var key in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "text");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }
}
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass routevalues into the redirect

```
public actionresult search(string city, datetime date ){

 return RedirectToAction("search", "home",  new { date = date,city=city });
}
```

Comment: if you make ajax call Ajax calls, Stephen Muecke said ,ajax call  stay on the same page so return RedirectToAction("search"); in your method is just ignored.

Comment: Yes the browser stays on the same page, but the request will nevertheless be redirected and the result returned to the success handler

Comment: Do you want to use Ajax and still have readable URLs? There is no out of the box solution for that. Look into Html5 pushState for evergreen browsers or the not so beautifull solution with Hash-parameters for older browsers

Comment: thank you, there is't any way for pass the parameters without session or cookie ?

Comment: I thought you want an url like websitename/flight/London. Do you want the parameters in the url or not?